# Modifying a onkeyup event to ignore Tab keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#textboxA").keyup(function () {
var message;
message ="Currently Textbox A in use";
$("#error").slideDown("fast");
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

});

$("#textboxB").keyup(function () {
var message;
message ="Currently Textbox B in use";
$("#error").slideDown("fast");
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

});    

});
```

In my above code, whenever I press tab key to move from my textboxA to textboxB, the jquery function is triggering and it showing the message. How to prevent that ?

[**Fiddle setup here**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/jtJBY/)

Comment: When is it mean to trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure the tab key isn't pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textboxA").keyup(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode != 9){
             var message;
             message ="Currently Textbox A in use";
             $("#error").slideDown("fast");
             document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

             });

       $("#textboxB").keyup(function (e) {
             if(e.keyCode != 9){
             var message;
             message ="Currently Textbox B in use";
             $("#error").slideDown("fast");
             document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=message;

             });  
             }

       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple check for tab `keyCode`.If its not tab key then execute.Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textboxA").keyup(function (e) {
        var message;
        message = "Currently Textbox A in use";
        if (e.keyCode != 9) {
            $("#error").slideDown("fast");
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = message;
        }
    });

    $("#textboxB").keyup(function (e) {
        var message;
        message = "Currently Textbox B in use";
        if (e.keyCode != 9) {
            $("#error").slideDown("fast");
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = message;
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtJBY/1/)